# What do the options do on the clear type configuration tool

Tags: settings, cleartype

I am trying to set up clear type for my monitor, it has a bgr layout. I do not understand the settings in the cleartype text tuner.

All buttons say "The quickbrown fox..." and ask me to make a judgement. I would like to at least be able to select with confidence the subpixle layout, than make a judgement (it necessary) on the other stuff.

I do not have the time to do a multi-user double blind trial.

So what do the buttons do?, at a technical level.

Answer (score 0):

Each version have some minor difference in colors. Depending on who is reading them you should see a difference and you could have a different choice.

> According to MSDN website,[5] Microsoft acknowledges that "[t]ext that
>   is rendered with ClearType can also appear significantly different
>   when viewed by individuals with varying levels of color sensitivity.
>   Some individuals can detect slight differences in color better than
>   others." This opinion is shared[6] by the font designer Thomas
>   Phinney, program manager for fonts and core technologies at Adobe
>   Systems:[7] "There is also considerable variation between individuals
>   in their sensitivity to color fringing. Some people just notice it and
>   are bothered by it a lot more than others."
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType

Comment: Not an answer to what I asked, but some useful info all the same. Thanks.